# Creating Standalone Matlab Application That Connects to MYSQL

Tags: mysql, matlab, matlab-compiler

I have quite a few Matlab scripts that connect to a MYSQL database to retrieve or update tables. I am required to create a standalone application from the Matlab scripts that I have made.

I want to know whether it is possible to create a standalone MATLAB application that connects to MYSQL through the Matlab Compiler or would I have to find an alternative way.

If there is an alternative, could you please suggest it.

I am using Matlab 8 with the database toolbox to connect to SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to use MATLAB Compiler to create a standalone executable from your MATLAB application. Database Toolbox is supported by MATLAB Compiler, and any access to MySQL that works successfully in your MATLAB application should work the same in your standalone executable.